# How to print text between two line numbers into a new file in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a file like this (numbers on first column is line number)

```
30.<unit id=20>
31....
32.</unit>
33.<unit id=40?
34....
35.</unit>
36<unit id=20>
37...
38.</unit>
39.<unit id=40?
40....
41</unit>
```

I want to print lines between two line numbers, say 32 and 39. How can I accomplish this in Unix?
I'm new to unix. 
Note: I don't want perl scripts please.

Comment: Which shell? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sed`

```
sed -n '/^32/,/^39/p' file
```

Comment: Thanks. There is small change now. Consider I don't have to manually input line numbers. I have a file like this: 
13|20
35|45
75|96
546|633

I need a script for read this file for the line numbers and each of them in a new file.
Thanks.

Comment: @Siva  - Upvote the answers to this question that you like. Mark one as the most appropriate answer (green check mark) and then post a new question

Comment: This somehow fails the answer with the highest votes work

Answer (score 8):

Another way with sed:

```
 sed -n '32,39p' filename
```

Comment: Thanks. There is small change now. Consider I don't have to manually input line numbers. I have a file like this: 
13|20
35|45
75|96
546|633

I need a script for read this file for the line numbers and each of them in a new file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '32,39p' input > output
```

Note that this ignores your line numbering and simply prints lines 32 through 39.  If you want to match the strings, use something like Fredrik's proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks. There is small change now. Consider I don't have to manually input line numbers. I have a file like this: 
13|20
35|45
75|96
546|633

I need a script for read this file for the line numbers and each of them in a new file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try this

```
sed '32,39!d' input > output
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.