# Print text between two lines (from list of line numbers in file) in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a sample file which has thousands of lines.
I want to print text between two line numbers in that file. I don't want to input line numbers manually, rather I have a file which contains list of line numbers between which text has to be printed.

Example : `linenumbers.txt`

```
345|789
999|1056
1522|1366
3523|3562
```

I need a shell script which will read line numbers from this file and print the text between each range of lines into a separate (new) file.

That is, it should print lines between 345 and 789 into a new file, say `File1.txt`, and print text between lines 999 and 1056 into a new file, say `File2.txt`, and so on.

Comment: The probability that you will receive an answer in the future increases dramatically if you do some research first and post what you have tried...

Comment: It seems this question was response to a comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14983117/2451238) to [a similar question by the same user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14982942/2451238). While both of them are not best questions if have read, I still think it is clear and on topic what the questions are about and there is enough information to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

considering your target file has only thousands of lines. here is a quick and dirty solution.

```
awk -F'|' '{system("sed -n \""$1","$2"p\" targetFile > file"NR)}' linenumbers.txt
```

- the `targetFile` is your file containing thousands of lines.
- the oneliner does **not** require your `linenumbers.txt` to be sorted.
- the oneliner allows line range to be overlapped in your `linenumbers.txt`

after running the command above, you will have n `filex` files. `n` is the row counts of `linenumbers.txt` `x` is from `1-n` you can change the filename pattern as you want.

Comment: @Fredrik I thought about awk one process with two files arguments. it is doable too. however not like `NR>=$1 && NR<=$2` you have to store linenumbers in array, and store the target file in array, then do line range checking. we need either 3 arrays or two arrays and one split. I was just lazy to play with those, so as mentioned, went to the **dirty and quick** way. AND, if sort not required and range overlapping is allowed. we have to loop the targetfile array n times.

Comment: jupp, I realized that and deleted my comment :-) +1

Comment: Kent, this will fail for the third line `1522|1366`. The fix involves testing which number is highest or lowest out of the two. Then storing these in variables and using them inside your `sed`. It's going to get more dirty :-)

Comment: @Steve: I would regard that as a bug in the data.  If there's a problem such that it has to be dealt with, then a simple pre-filter deals with it: `awk -F'|' '{ if ($1 <= $2) print $1 "|" $2; else print $2 "|" $1 }`, or (more likely) combine this with the main answer: `awk -F'|' '{if ($1 <= $2) { lo=$1; hi=$2; } else { lo=$2; hi=$1; } cmd=sprintf("sed -n ...", lo, hi, NR); system(cmd)}'`.  But it would be a lot simpler if the system that generated the line numbers in the first place was fixed so it didn't produce reversed ranges.

Comment: If the sample data is only megabytes (rather than gigabytes or terabytes), this solution is OK.  The trouble with big files is that it runs a `sed` command for each set of line numbers, making multiple passes over the sample data, instead of making just one pass over the sample data.

Comment: @Kent @ Steve, @ Jonathan,  - Sorry, the third data(1522|1366) was wrong. The line numbers will be in in ascending order. Thanks, it worked !

Comment: @Kent BTW, can you explain what happens in the command.

Comment: @Siva: I have updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk numbers.txt file.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    # set the field separator
    FS="|"
}

# for the first file in the arguments list
FNR==NR {

    # add the row number and field one as keys to a multidimensional array with
    # a value of field two
    a[NR][$1]=$2

    # skip processing the rest of the code
    next
}

# for the second file in the arguments list
{
    # for every element in the array's first dimension
    for (i in a) {

        # for every element in the second dimension
        for (j in a[i]) {

            # ensure that the first field is treated numerically
            j+=0

            # if the line number is greater than the first field
            # and smaller than the second field
            if (FNR>=j && FNR<=a[i][j]) {

                # print the line to a file with the suffix of the first file's 
                # line number (the first dimension)
                print > "File" i
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "|" 'FNR==NR { a[NR][$1]=$2; next } { for (i in a) for (j in a[i]) { j+=0; if (FNR>=j && FNR<=a[i][j]) print > "File" i } }' numbers.txt file.txt
```

---

---

---

If you have an 'old' `awk`, here's the version with compatibility. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk numbers.txt file.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    # set the field separator
    FS="|"
}

# for the first file in the arguments list
FNR==NR {

    # add the row number and field one as a key to a pseudo-multidimensional
    # array with a value of field two
    a[NR,$1]=$2

    # skip processing the rest of the code
    next
}

# for the second file in the arguments list
{
    # for every element in the array
    for (i in a) {

        # split the element in to another array
        # b[1] is the row number and b[2] is the first field 
        split(i,b,SUBSEP)

        # if the line number is greater than the first field
        # and smaller than the second field
        if (FNR>=b[2] && FNR<=a[i]) {

            # print the line to a file with the suffix of the first file's
            # line number (the first pseudo-dimension)
            print > "File" b[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "|" 'FNR==NR { a[NR,$1]=$2; next } { for (i in a) { split(i,b,SUBSEP); if (FNR>=b[2] && FNR<=a[i]) print > "File" b[1] } }' numbers.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you please explain script.awk file. And also the awk one liner

Comment: @Siva: I've added some comments for you. I hope they're useful. The one-liners are exactly the same as their script counterparts. The code is just easier to read and maintain in script form. The code works by adding the contents of `numbers.txt` to an array, then iterating through the big file once, printing to each output file as required. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
# myscript.sh
linenumbers="linenumber.txt"
somefile="afile"
while IFS=\| read start  end ; do
    echo "sed -n '$start,${end}p;${end}q;' $somefile  > $somefile-$start-$end"
done < $linenumbers
```

run it like so `sh myscript.sh`

```
sed -n '345,789p;789q;' afile  > afile-345-789
sed -n '999,1056p;1056q;' afile  > afile-999-1056
sed -n '1522,1366p;1366q;' afile  > afile-1522-1366
sed -n '3523,3562p;3562q;' afile  > afile-3523-3562
```

then when you're happy do `sh myscript.sh | sh`

**EDIT** Added William's excellent points on style and correctness.

**EDIT** Explanation

The basic idea is to get a script to generate a series of shell commands that can be checked for correctness first before being executed by "| sh".

`sed -n '345,789p;789q;`  means use `sed` and don't echo each line (-n) ; there are two commands saying from line 345 to 789 p(rint) the lines and the second command is at line 789 q(uit) - by quitting on the last line you save having `sed` read all the input file.

The `while` loop reads from the $linenumbers file using read, `read` if given more than one variable name populates each with a field from the input, a field is usually separated by <kbd>space</kbd> and if there are too few variable names then `read` will put the remaining data into the last variable name.

You can put the following in at your shell prompt to understand that behaviour.

```
ls -l | while read first rest ; do
   echo $first XXXX $rest
done
```

Try adding another variable `second` to the above to see what happens then, it should be obvious.

The problem is your data is delimited by <kbd>|</kbd>s and that's where using William's suggestion of `IFS=\|` works as now when reading from the input the [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) has changed and the input is now separated by <kbd>|</kbd>s  and we get the desired result.

**Others can feel free to edit,correct and expand.**

Comment: Rather than using `tr` to convert the separator, you can simply do: `while IFS=\| read start end; do ...; done < $linenumbers`

Comment: You really want to add `-n` to the sed invocation.

Comment: Thanks William good points. I didn't realise ``IFS=\|`` would have scope like that - I've often done setting ``IFS=xx`` and then ``set -- $MYVAR`` to capture values in ``$*`` - So cheers for that.

Comment: @sotapme Thanks. It worked. Could you please explain the script.

Comment: Tried to explain the workings.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sed` to process the sample data file because it is simple and swift.  This requires a mechanism for converting the line numbers file into the appropriate `sed` script.  There are many ways to do this.

One way uses `sed` to convert the set of line numbers into a `sed` script.  If everything was going to standard output, this would be trivial.  With the output needing to go to different files, we need a line number for each line in the line numbers file.  One way to give line numbers is the [`nl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html) command.  Another possibility would be to use [`pr -n -l1`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html). The same `sed` command line works with both:

```
nl linenumbers.txt |
sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)|\([0-9]*\)/\2,\3w file\1.txt/'
```

For the given data file, that generates:

```
345,789w > file1.txt
999,1056w > file2.txt
1522,1366w > file3.txt
3523,3562w > file4.txt
```

Another option would be to have `awk` generate the `sed` script:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%d,%dw > file%d.txt\n", $1, $2, NR }' linenumbers.txt
```

If your version of `sed` will allow you to read its script from standard input with `-f -` (GNU `sed` does; BSD `sed` does not), then you can convert the line numbers file into a `sed` script on the fly, and use that to parse the sample data:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%d,%dw > file%d.txt\n", $1, $2, NR }' linenumbers.txt |
sed -n -f - sample.data
```

If your system supports `/dev/stdin`, you can use one of:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%d,%dw > file%d.txt\n", $1, $2, NR }' linenumbers.txt |
sed -n -f /dev/stdin sample.data

awk -F'|' '{ printf "%d,%dw > file%d.txt\n", $1, $2, NR }' linenumbers.txt |
sed -n -f /dev/fd/0 sample.data
```

Failing that, use an explicit script file:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%d,%dw > file%d.txt\n", $1, $2, NR }' linenumbers.txt > sed.script
sed -n -f sed.script sample.data
rm -f sed.script
```

Strictly, you should deal with ensuring the temporary file name is unique (`mktemp`) and removed even if the script is interrupted (`trap`):

```
tmp=$(mktemp sed.script.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

awk -F'|' '{ printf "%d,%dw > file%d.txt\n", $1, $2, NR }' linenumbers.txt > $tmp
sed -n -f $tmp sample.data
rm -f $tmp
trap 0
```

The final `trap 0` allows your script to exit successfully; omit it, and you script will always exit with status 1.

I've ignored Perl and Python; either could be used for this in a single command.  The file management is just fiddly enough that using `sed` seems simpler.  You could also use just `awk`, either with a first `awk` script writing an `awk` script to do the heavy duty work (trivial extension of the above), or having a single `awk` process read both files and produce the required output (harder, but far from impossible).

If nothing else, this shows that there are many possible ways of doing the job.  If this is a one-off exercise, it really doesn't matter very much which you choose.  If you will be doing this repeatedly, then choose the mechanism that you like.  If you're worried about performance, measure.  It is likely that converting the line numbers into a command script is a negligible cost; processing the sample data with the command script is where the time is taken.  I would expect `sed` to excel at that point; I've not measured to confirm that it does.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first field from `345|789` you can e.g use awk

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1}'
```

Combine that with the answers received from your other question and you will have a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Fredrik , but I am afraid that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(.*)\|(.*)/\1,\2w file-\1-\2.txt/' | sed -nf - file
```